# How to grep in Windows for for eval code?

Tags: windows, grep, find, malware

I have written this code in Linux, How can I achieve the same in Windows server ?

```
find "dirname" -name "*.php" -exec grep -PHl "(eval\(.*\);)" {} \;
```

Basically I want to find out this pattern

> eval(something here);

Comment: Please add some context to explain the code sections

Comment: to do clever regexes in windows, you use cygwin(a program you must install on windows if you are even a fraction of a linux geek) and do the linux commands, or there can often be ways to do things in powershell which is very powerful

Comment: why say ""dirname"" it sounds like a filename particularly as you are saying `*.php`

Comment: What does the 1 do in PH1?

Comment: And your regex might be quite simple in which case cmd's 'find' can do it(with a for /f)..

Comment: Also perhaps you want to escape  the outtermost round brackets `"\(eval\(.*\);\)"`  if they are  literals.   Or if they are not literals, then remove them `"eval\(.*\);"` 'cos they aren't doing anything . 'cos if they are unescaped they are for grouping and you're not doing anything with the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always using `MinGW` and `MSys` (or `MSYS2`) on Windows to do what you specified in the question, which come with `find`, `grep` and many other commonly used Unix commands.

Comment: MSys (or MSYS2) ==> This seems to be far better. As a Linux System admin, MSYS2 is a great tool to manage windows based server.

I can mostly reuse my linux script to manage the Windows server. Thanks.